# ngx-charts heat map customize tooltip with tooltipTemplate

Tags: angular, tooltip, heatmap, ngx-charts

I tried to customize the tooltip of ngx-charts-heat-map with this code

```
<ng-template #tooltipTemplate let-item="item">
  <h1>
    {{getFlag(item.name)}}
  </h1>
  <h2>{{item.name}}: {{item.value}}</h2>
</ng-template>
```

I realize this work just fine if the data is single object array, but not the multi object ones

```
export var single = [
  {
    "name": "Germany",
    "value": 8940000
  },
  {
    "name": "USA",
    "value": 5000000
  },
  {
    "name": "France",
    "value": 7200000
  }
];

export var multi = [
  {
    "name": "Germany",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "2010",
        "value": 7300000
      },
      {
        "name": "2011",
        "value": 8940000
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "name": "USA",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "2010",
        "value": 7870000
      },
      {
        "name": "2011",
        "value": 8270000
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "name": "France",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "2010",
        "value": 5000002
      },
      {
        "name": "2011",
        "value": 5800000
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

the ngx-charts-heat-map only allow for multi object, is there any way for customize the tooltip? and probably the legend as well

Answer (score 4):

Use a template of the following form within an `<ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d>` (or similar) chart element:

```
<ng-template #tooltipTemplate let-model="model">
    <!-- fields are series/name/value -->
    <div class="tt">
      {{ model.series }}
      | {{ model.name }}
      | {{ model.value }}
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

StackBlitz example based on example forked from current docs: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vertical-bar-chart-kfjrxe

Comment: Yes but the tooltip is placed at the end of the <app-root> so your component stylesheet is useless. Specify the styles in the html or the global stylesheet.